# Should I change a curve to mesh when modeling?

Tags: modeling, mesh, export, bezier-curves

I created an object as below:

[image: shape with bezier curve & geometry extruding]

Front view

[image: front view]

**1. Should I convert this curve to a mesh for export?** My final goal is to export this object to an .obj/fbx file and use it in javascript, ARKit, games, or any universal format for 3D objects. I have multiple mesh objects in this scene (file). What would be the most clean and conventional/agreed way to create a final model?

**2. Should I convert it to mesh only if I want to get rendered scenes (jpgs)?** 
If I don't need an .obj file but want to only render several scenes, can I leave them as vector curves?

Comment: If exporting to obj or fbx afaik object will be converted to mesh either way, so better to convert it yourself to keep track of topology. If rendering you can go with curve as long as you add bevel to the object (either simple bevel or assiging a bevel object in curve properties) as by default curve itself won't be rendered with e.g. Cycles (no thickness in geometry).

Comment: Thanks @MrZak. good to know they will be converted to mesh.